# Remove negative sign from unicode string in python and Spark

Tags: python, unicode, apache-spark

I have a dataset where one of the columns has `negative sign (-)` in front of some numbers in that column and the data is in `unicode string`. I want to remove `-` sign from in front of the numbers that have. This is what I tried:

```
def extract(line):

    #label = '{:,.2f}'.format(abs(line[4]))
    label = '{:,.2f}'.format(str(float(line[4]))).lstrip("-")
    return (line[0],line[1],line[2],line[3],label)

Data = sc.textFile('file1.csv').zipWithIndex().filter(lambda (line,rownum): rownum>0).map(lambda (line, rownum): line)

input_rdd = (inputData
    .map(lambda line: line.split(","))
    .filter(lambda line: len(line) >1 )
    .map(extract)) 

input_data = input_rdd.collect()
```

When I execute this I get error as: `ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'`. I tried to use `abs()` also (line commented out in my code above) but that also throws error as `wrong type for abs()`. How can I remove the `-` sign from `unicode string`?

This is what my sample data looks like:

```
Level1,Male,New York,New York,3528 
Level2,Male,Columbus,Ohio,-4958
```

If I do just `return (line[0],line[1],line[2],line[3],line[4])` in my code above and print the rdd then I get this:

```
[(u'Level1', u'Male', u'New York', u'New York', u'3528'), (u'Level2', u'Male', u'Columbus', u'Ohio', u'-4958'),....]
```

As you can see some values in last column of each row or element is negative unicode string.

Comment: as it seems you are using the numbers as labels so conversion to float and then to string once again just to use `abs()` seems not so elegant of a solution. better use `re`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the columns you specifically want are 0, 1, 2, 3, and the last column (formatted) then try this:

```
def extract(line):
    return (line[:4]) + ('{:,.2f}'.format(abs(float(line[-1]))),)
```

Comment: when I try to do `label = '{:,.2f}'.format(abs(float(str(line[14]))))` it seems it is doing float() on whole data instead of just one column of line[14]. And it throws error on trying to convert string to float

Comment: @JasonDonnald Would you mind posting an example of what one of your rows looks like?

Comment: I have added a sample of data in my post above

Comment: the last numeric in each element has negative unicode strings(some of them)

Comment: @JasonDonnald Thank you for posting sample data. After the formatting, do you want to place the formatted data back into the dataset? So your second item in the sample data would become `(u'Level2', u'Male', u'Columbus', u'Ohio', u'4,958.00')` or do just want u'4,958.00'?

Comment: From the look of it, you're just indexing wrong. If your data looks like what you posted above, you want line[1][-1], not line[14]. You're looking for the last element of the second tuple in each line, not the 15th element.

Comment: @AdamAcosta I have updated my code in above post. I am doing line[4] to access last column

Comment: @asadmshah I basically just want to remove the - sign.

Comment: @JasonDonnald Updated my post. Try it out now

Comment: @asadmshah so as per your update, you are  returning the whole `line`. Actually in my csv file there are few more columns in each row which I am filtering out. Thats why in `extract()` I am doing `line[0]`,`line[1]` and so on as these are the only columns I want to retain

Comment: In my sample data that I have posted I am not showing all the columns but just the ones I want to retain. But in csv there are few additional columns in each row

Comment: `return (line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4].lstrip('-'))` should do what you're looking to do if all you want to do is remove the negative sign and not actually format the number with a decimal point and trailing zeros.

Answer (score 0):

why not use `re` module 
It has method called `sub` which can be used to substitute characters.
in you case

`re.sub("-","","-6.789")`

`=> 6.789`